# Android: conversion from bitmap to Byte[] OutOfMemory error

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, arrays, bmp

I try to convert an image saved on the phone's storage (.jpg) to a bitmap and after to convert this bitmap to a byte[] to upload this image on a DB.

```
public void insertData() {
        File file = new File(photoUrl);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        bytes = stream.toByteArray();
        DBConnUpdate conn = new DBConnUpdate();
        conn.execute(   "insert into test (img, name) "+
                        "values ( '"+ bytes +"', '"+ productName +"')");

    }
```

but it doesn't works beacause of an OutOfMemory error here:

```
bytes = stream.toByteArray();
```

Why?

Comment: Do not store bitmap bytes in Database instead store the file path in the database.You are getting out of memory since the bytes array is too large to hold in dalvik virtual machine instance memory.

Comment: I need the image can be visible to other devices. Morover if I try to convert directly the .jpg file to bite[] it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try This Code:-


 BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                 options.inDither = false;
                 options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                 options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                 options.inSampleSize = 1;
                 options.inPurgeable = true;
                 options.inPreferQualityOverSpeed = true;
                 options.inTempStorage=new byte[32 * 1024];

    File file = new File(photoUrl);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), options);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, stream);
            bytes = stream.toByteArray();
```

Comment: This code add manifest file in
<application
        android:largeHeap="true"